# UNITY Vertex Color from obj or dae (fdx)

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, 3d, vertex-shader, vertex

I have been googling hard for days to find a solution for this without luck.
I am basically trying to import vertex colours from.one of the above formats and interpolate between them to get a smooth Color profile across the surface.
The obj and dae file have a vertex (xyz) as well as 3 other values (I assume RGB) associated with each vertex (when viewed in an text editor). However when I import the asset, it comes in without any Color. The material is set and uneditable by default and I just can't work out how to get these colours displayed.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a way around it.
Basically, if you import a dae file with vertex colors a Vertex Shader (Standard) is available which seems to work very well.
Initially I was messing around with objs and it looks like that does not work as well but I will have to try that again tonight!